# What to make with hundreds of 555 chips

Tags: 555

This is a little bit different question than normal..

Aliexpress is ruing my life, sometimes i order things i don't even need because it seems cool. A few time ago I ordered 500x 555 chips for just a few bucks, haven't used one.

What cool project could I do with so many 555 chips? I'm open to every absurd, stupid, usefull and non-usefull or original projects.

Maybe a predator style giant clock? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyBwKHCtgm0

Or maybe just a random LED blinking matrix with nothing usefull.

Open to every suggestions :)

Comment: [How about a monochrome mosaic?](http://www.google.de/search?q=monochrome+mosaic)

Comment: Will 500 black dots be enough to draw the 555's schematic or block diagram? If so arrange them that way on a piece of white cardboard.

Comment: "*Aliexpress is ruing my life*", okay.

Comment: StackExchange is focused more on answering specific questions than on having conversations about open-ended questions. I suspect that if you ask this question in a good Reddit community, you'll get more interesting ideas ;)

Comment: there is at least one [dedicated website](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/) made for your problem (the "what to do with 555s" problem, not the Aliexpress related one).

Comment: Put them into a drawer.

Comment: @Chupacabras you comment and vote to close.  That's not kosher.

Comment: @HarrySvensson you comment and vote to close.  That's not kosher.

Comment: @Misunderstood It is halal.

Comment: @Misunderstood Why do you consider it is not kosher? It is absolutely OK.

Comment: @Chupacabras you thought the question should be closed but you thought it was valid enough to comment.  Like you are playing both sides of the fence.  My comment was not serious.

Answer (score 10):

Purchase 500 741 op amps. Then go around to schools giving the 741 and 555 
 away as examples of antique circuits

Comment: ... antique circuits with terrible characteristics that nobody should be forced to use. See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486156/replacements-for-ne555-circuits-or-why-and-how-should-i-replace-my-ne555

Answer (score 8):

My first inspiration that is somewhat silly would be to create some kind of chain reaction circuit where you press one button and then it trigger a 555 that then trigger other 555. each 555 will also light a LED to indicate where the chain reaction is occuring. That way you get your own small scale nuclear chain reaction simulator. You can play with different propagation frequencies and different arrangements. I'd set them up in such a way that you can easily switch the explosion pattern.

Comment: Yeah, 555 dominoes is an idea!

Comment: This answer likely triggered an NSA alarm.

Comment: I can confirm you that I'm still alive and that NSA didn't knock at my door yet. Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 3):

**555 earrings**

[image]

*Figure 1. These are FIN05 / 5640 earrings that were available on [Etsy](http://etsy.com) but they're out of stock.*

There's a gap in the market. Go for it!

How quickly can you make them? (Timing is everything!)

Comment: +1 for "Timing is everything!"

Comment: What does "FIN05 / 5640" mean?

Comment: I have no idea. It's what's printed on the chips. Have a look on the [Pinterest page](https://www.pinterest.ie/pin/431712314255368932/) where I found them. There's enough resolution if you zoom in. I was wondering if someone else could identify them.

Answer (score 0):

To save some money, next time buy components without the corner hole to screw it on a PCB / proto plate, but use one or more 555's and glue your component on top of the 555. Just to use them as kind of spacer.

Comment: smd dead bug protoboards?

Comment: I actually meant DIP8 555's. I used them one time to stick a component on top of a breadboard. Like placing a 555 normally into a breadboard (make sure the pins are not creating problems for the 'real'  circuit. And instead of glue I put an elastic under the 555 and around the component which was 'placed'  on top of the 555. Worked quite well as temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

One NE555 [contains 25 transistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC) (some sources say 24). That's giving you the solid number of 12500 transistors, which is more than in a [Z80 microprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count) at ~8500. If they were neurons, you'd have the vast computational power of a [sea slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_sea_hare) brain at your disposal.
So don't expect your 555s soldered together on ~500cm² of PCB, each with their own old-style 100nF cap next to it, to develop a consciousness, but a Turing machine should be doable. At least you won't need an external clock.