# how to solve the phase shift of a ne555 timer

Tags: pwm, oscillator, trigger, 555

[image: wave form and schematic diagram]
Why is the first pulse wave is not the same as the rest of the wave in this 555 timer?

Is there any way to remove the wave before 2 ms or is there anyway to make it same as the rest in the graph.

Comment: yeah, you're still using the wrong components for your job. How about you drop *both* the NE555 and the OP 741, and start from scratch, and design something that does your *job* instead of trying to somehow use the two worst chips in existence (little exaggeration needed there).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP does not incorporate feedback from previous questions – the LM741 is still operated with input 2V below its negative supply rail, and with a too low positive supply. None of this would work. Since OP doesn't incorporate feedback, there's little expectation for benefits too them or future readers.

Comment: I vote to keep it open.  He asked two questions and eventually got answers that were on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely only happens at the power-on situation because the capacitor on the 555 has to begin its charging sequence from 0 volts. In all other cases, the capacitor never gets fully discharged hence, it behaves properly.

[Reasons not to use the NE555](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486156/is-the-ne555-the-ic-i-need-and-if-not-what-do-i-replace-it-with/486157)

Also problematic is that the 741 (a dinosaur that was developed before a man landed on the moon) is not rated to run on an 8 volt supply - it needs at least 10 volts.

Also, you are feeding an AC signal into a 741 input that can go 2 volts below the most negative pin on the 741 and this is likely to cause problems if not damage the part.

Given also that the common-mode input range does not extend to it's negative rail pin, you are likely to get very surprising results in real life and quite possibly when using the simulation.

[Reasons not to use a 741](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522#304522).

May I also remind you of something I said on your previous question: -

*You need to find an op-amp that can handle below the negative rail input signals. There are few (not many and maybe hard to get). But when you do find one you will have a sinewave to square wave circuit and then you need to convert edges to pulses hence what I said about an RC circuit and an exclusive or gate.*

So, use an exclusive or gate to turn a square wave (green) into a pulse output (red): -

[image]

Comment: Is there an equivalent link for *Reasons not to use NE555*?

Comment: @AJN if not and you feel up-to-the-task, please feel free.

Comment: @AJN, Andy guess who wrote a longer Q&A about that? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/486156/is-the-ne555-the-ic-i-need-and-if-not-what-do-i-replace-it-with/486157#486157

Comment: @MarcusMüller pesky hijacker LOL

Comment: @Andyaka lol :) "please feel free"--> I felt **very** free. A bit freeloaderish ;)

Comment: how do i count the value for the resistor and capacitor?

Comment: Try 1 kohm and 10 nF to start with. If that produces a pulse that's too wide then lower C to 1 nF or 100 pF.

Comment: uhmm is there like a formula for it i need the calculation to justify why i choose this value

Comment: The time delay is approximately C * R so, for 1 kohm and 10 nF that's a time delay of 10 us. You might want longer of course.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to remove the wave before 2 ms or is there anyway to make it same as the rest in the graph.

Yes. First, you remove your NE555 from your design approach. It doesn't help you in any way I can think of when trying to convert a sine wave to an impulse comb.

Then, you remove the 741. It doesn't help you in any way when trying to convert a sine wave to an impulse comb, unless you have a large bipolar power supply, which you don't seem to have. Even then, it would be the least sensible opamp to use – many, many other opamps would be better.

Answer (score 1):

In the first half-cycle after power-on, the timing 555 capacitor charges from 0 V to (0.67 x Vcc) V.  For all subsequent half-cycles, the timing capacitor voltage varies between 0.67 Vcc and 0.33 Vcc.  The capacitor voltage never goes down to 0 V again, so that longer half-cycle is not repeated.

Comment: While what you write in this answer is correct, it's technically irrelevant: the LM741 is operated with a unipolar supply, but input that drops below, and would be malfunctioning or even get damaged in this application. Also, you're not answering the question OP posted (how to dix this?) ;)

Comment: MM, are you serious?