# Isolated voltage measurement circuit or sensor

Tags: voltage-measurement, isolated

Which circuit or sensor can measure a voltage range of 24 V DC (the power supply for a motor)? The circuit is fully galvanically isolated from the ESP32 used. Does anyone have any ideas on how to measure this voltage?[image]

Comment: It would be highly unusual for anyone to use a linear 0 - 50 V supply for motor control these days. Most controllers would use PWM (pulse-width modulation) of the 50 V supply and this would just require an opto isolator to pass the PWM signal back to the ESP32 which could work out the duty cycle. Are you sure you're asking the right question? There *is* a chance that they're using some sort of SMPS to adjust a steady DC voltage though. You should check.

Comment: We want to monitor the battery voltage of our motor (24 V)which is on the output side of opto i.e. on the photodiode side, the volatge sensor we were previously using had input and output ground shorted which is a problem

Comment: 1. Your question says 0 - 50 V. Your comment says 24 V. Which is it? If it's a nominal 24 V supply then monitoring over 16 - 30 V would probably be plenty. 2. "*... on the output side of opto*" What opto? I think it's time for a schematic diagram and some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s acceptable that you can’t measure the voltage when it’s very low or zero, you could run a separate circuit from the motor supply voltage, use an ADC to measure the voltage and a UART via an opto isolator to transmit the voltage periodically.  Would that fit your needs?  This would require little more than a voltage regulator, a small microcontroller and an opto.

Comment: We want to monitor the battery voltage of our motor which is on the output side of opto i.e. on the photodiode side, the volatge sensor we were previously using had input and output ground shorted which was a problem

Comment: @YuktaSanghvi, OK, but is it okay if you can only measure in the range of, say, 10-50 V instead of 0 - 50 V?

Answer (score 0):

I find the Sigma-Delta isolated adc to be the most cost effective way to measure all things around the motor. You will need something to filter/decode the SD stream. Ti has it embedded, simple filters are easily built in fpga.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Convert the supply voltage into PWM using a comparator or even op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/602608/237061).
2. Transmit via opto to MCU side
3. Read duty cycle with hardware counter.

Needs only a few standard components (<<1€) which are likely in your BOM already.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

Don't isolate the power circuit from your micro. This way, the micro can directly interface with all the power components.

Instead, isolate your micro's interface with the rest of the world (serial, wifi, etc).